# How to get quantity of duplicates in array nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the quantity of for example: `DragonBall`, it would return `x3` or `Featured` it would return x2 etc, however I have tried this method with just the spammed response of `2`

```js
let data = mockdata.forEach(function (i) {
      count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
      console.log(count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1)
});
```

```json
[
  'Daily',
  'DragonBall1B',
  'DragonBall2B',
  'DragonBall3B',
  'Featured',
  'Featured2',
  'SquadOrigins',
  'SquadOrigins2'
]
```

API used to retrieve the above information:
https://fortnitecontent-website-prod07.ol.epicgames.com/content/api/pages/fortnite-game/shop-sections

Comment: There's no magic sauce here.  If you want to find out how many matches or partial matches of some string exist in the array, you have to iterate through the whole array and search every single element for a particular full or partial match and count them as you go.

Comment: This question is just not clear.  It appears in other comments that there's lots more to your real question than is explained here.  Please add lots more detail here to explain EXACTLY what you want here.  Show a function definition you want implemented, specify  the precise arguments it gets passed, describe what it is supposed to and then show the desired input and output.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can remove the first instance of digits (along with whatever follows) to get you to the key you're interested in grouping on.

```js
const mockdata = [
  'Daily',
  'DragonBall1B',
  'DragonBall2B',
  'DragonBall3B',
  'Featured',
  'Featured2',
  'SquadOrigins',
  'SquadOrigins2'
]
const count = {};
mockdata.forEach((str) => {
  const key = str.replace(/\d+.*/, '');
  count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(count.DragonBall);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are other numbers anywhere else in the string preceding the ones that relate to quantity

Comment: It's up to OP to clarify, but if that sort of format is a possibility, and the desire is to only remove the final instance of digits, the regular expression could be switched to `\d+\D*$`

Comment: This is similar to what I am after however I'm retrieving the data from an API, so the output is different every 24hrs.

Comment: @Johnty How does that make the problem different? Does that mean that taking the non-digit starting characters no longer works?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it makes the function `count.DragonBall` unusable as the output could differ as for example `LebronA` or `Marvel2` etc... the items in the API change every 24hr cycle

Comment: `count.DragonBall` is not a `function`. `count` is an object & `DragonBall` is a prop/key in that object. `count.DragonBall` will get the corresponding value (for said prop / key). It doesn't matter what the actual strings are: whether its `DragonBall` or `Marvel` or whatnot. With the above code, as long as you know which string's count you need, simply doing `count.DragonBall` or `count.Marvel` will get the count. If you are unaware of which one to check but have to go through all, iterate through the `count` object's entries using `Object.entries(count)` array.

Comment: @jsN00b I get this response using `Object.entries(count)` ```[ [ 'Daily', 1 ], [ 'DragonBall', 3 ], [ 'Featured', 2 ] ]```

Comment: @Johnty What do the items in one API call have in common with the items in another? Comparing items in API calls over different days sounds like quite a different question than what you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73410552) - can you edit the question to clarify what you're actually looking for?

Comment: I've managed to get it with snippets of both Your code and @jsN00b

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  'Daily',
  'DragonBall1B',
  'DragonBall2B',
  'DragonBall3B',
  'Featured',
  'Featured2',
  'SquadOrigins',
  'SquadOrigins2'
]
const count = {};
arr.forEach((str) => {
        const key = str.replace(/\d+.*/, "");
        count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
      });
      let val = Object.entries(count);
      let itemName;
      let itemNum;
      let result = [];
      for (var i in val) {
        itemName = val[i][0];
        itemNum = val[i][1];
        result += `${itemName} (x${itemNum})\n`;
      }
       console.log(result);
```